# Knowing if a class is an eigenclass

Tags: ruby, eigenclass

What is the best way to tell if a class `some_class` is an eigenclass of some object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Prior to Ruby 2.0) The following expression evaluates to `true` if an only if the object `x` is an eigenclass:

```
Class === x && x.ancestors.first != x
```

The `===` equality check asserts that `x` is an instance of the `Class` class, the `!=` inequality check uses the fact that the `ancestors` introspection method "skips" eigenclasses.
For objects `x` that are instances of the `Object` class (i.e. `x` is not a blank slate object), the `Class === x` check is equivalent to `x.is_a? Class` or, in this particular case, to `x.instance_of? Class`.

Starting with Ruby 2.0, the above expression is not sufficient to detect eigenclasses since it evaluates to `true` also for classes that have `prepend`ed modules. This can be solved by an additional check that `x.ancestors.first` is not such a prepended module e.g. by `Class === x.ancestors.first`. Another solution is to modify the whole expression as follows:

```
Class === x && !x.ancestors.include?(x)
```

Answer (score 3):

There’s always brute force:

```
ObjectSpace.each_object.any? {|o| some_class.equal? (class << o; self; end)}
```

Comment: I can find the method `eigenclass` defined. On what module is it defined?

Comment: @sawa Sorry, I had defined it in my irb session.

Comment: Will `some_class == some_class.ancestors.first` or `some_class.ancestors.first == Class` also work?

Comment: @sawa That’s also true of `Class`.

Comment: You are right. So, as long as I consider `Class` as the only exception, it will work?

Answer (score 2):

In 2.1.0 at least, there's `Module.singleton_class?`:

```
Module.singleton_class?
#=> false
Module.new.singleton_class?
#=> false
Class.singleton_class?
#=> false
Class.new.singleton_class?
#=> false
Class.singleton_class
#=> #<Class:Class>
Class.singleton_class.singleton_class?
#=> true
```